# Mulesoft community version - How to consume response from SOAP Web Service

Tags: mule-studio, mule-component

I am developing flow (community version) to consume SOAP Web Service and store response into DB. So far I am able to get result from Web Service however I am not sure how to read response XML element.  I tried to use variable component with XPATH but didn't work. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

Assume that you have the below xml response from your web service

```
<Employee>
 <Name>John</Name>
 <ID>J234</ID>
 </Employee>
```

Please try the below syntax to fetch XML element

## [xpath3('/Employee/Name')]

Hope this will help you...